# I get an error "Request Log.enable failed" when run "node --inspect"

Tags: node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, inspect

I am trying to run node.js application with the new node 6.3+ --inspect feature (https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27)

But everytime I get the next error:

```
inspector.js:4418 Request Log.enable failed. {"code":-32601,"message":"'Log.enable' wasn't found"}
dispatchResponse @ inspector.js:4418
dispatch @ inspector.js:4372
_onMessage @ inspector.js:10555
```

I tried with node 6.9.0, 6.9.1, 7.0.0, chrome 54, chrome 56, windows 7/10. Nothing is working. 
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I was able to get log messages into console performing the next steps: 

1. switch to Sources tab;

2. close console drawer;

3. refresh page;

Little bit weird though...

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that uninstalling NiM (Node inspector Manager) on Chrome and manually copy pasting the URL into Chrome seems to get the console to work again.

Another workaround is to use another tool for debugging.

The Node documentation has a list: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/